# Why isn't jQuery able to access this imported global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, es6-modules

Trying to change a globally defined variable that I imported inside jQuery is causing a reference error:

global.js

```
export var w = window.innerWidth;
```

main.js

```
import {w} from './global.js';
console.log(w);
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    console.log(w);
    w = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(w);
});
```

The first two consoles print out the value, but the third gives a

`main.js:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: w is not defined`

Is it something to do with webpack? I see this in the dev tools:

```
console.log(_global_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["w"]);
w = window.innerWidth;
console.log(w);
```

Like it's not the same variable, but how do I make jQuery set the webpack variable?

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 module system, you cant reassign imported value from another module. Imported values are read only for other Modules. This is how it meant to be. Or else consumer would change the value of provider without knowledge of provider.

However you can give a way to change value from provider itself:

global.js : provider

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var changeW = function(newValue) {
   w = newValue;
}
export { w, changeW }
```

in main.js :

```
import {w,changeW} from './global.js';
console.log(w);
$(document).ready(function(){
...
   console.log(w);
   changeW(window.innerWidth); //call method to change value
   console.log(w);
});
```